# How to stop Trigger overwriting a custom field

Tags: apex, trigger

I have created a trigger to update a custom field called "Chiffre_d_affaire__c".
Anytime an **Order** with the status '**Activated**' is added to an account. The amount of the order should be added to the field "Chiffre_d_affaire__c".

So let's say my :
Chiffre_d_affaire__c = 100 000.00 ;
Order (TotalAmount) = 85 000.00 ;
the Chiffre_d_affaire__c should be updated to 185 000.00

But instead of adding to amount of the order to Chiffre_d_affaire__c;
The Trigger overwrite the 100 000.00 in Chiffre_d_affaire__c with the Order.
So Chiffre_d_affaire__c is updated with 85 000.00

How can I fix it?

Thanks

[image]

Order added to the Account:

[image]

Chiffre_d_affaire__c overwritten with the amount of the Order

[image]

Here is my Trigger

```
trigger UpdateAccountCA on Order (after update, before delete) {

    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
   
    if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
        //Iterate through each Order
        for(Order o : Trigger.new) {
            accountIds.add(o.AccountId);
        }
    }  
    else if(Trigger.isDelete) {
        for(Order o : Trigger.old) {
            accountIds.add(o.AccountId);
        }
    }
       
    AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT AccountId, SUM(TotalAmount)amt FROM Order WHERE AccountId In : accountIds  AND Status = 'Activated' GROUP BY AccountId];
   

    List<Account> toBeUpdateAccount = new List<Account>();
    for(AggregateResult Results: groupedResults) {
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Id = (id) Results.get('AccountId');
        acc.Chiffre_d_affaire__c = (Decimal)Results.get('amt');
        toBeUpdateAccount.add(acc);
    }
    update toBeUpdateAccount;
}
```

Comment: As it is a after trigger, you should Query the Chiffre_d_affaire__c and sum it.
This line here (acc.Chiffre_d_affaire__c = (Decimal)Results.get('amt');) is done exactly the result that you are seen

Comment: I would check the result of the query outside of the code to see if you are not missing something: `SELECT AccountId, SUM(TotalAmount)amt FROM Order WHERE AccountId In : accountIds  AND Status = 'Activated' GROUP BY AccountId`.

Comment: @Hermann Ouré, I see few more issues with your code in addition to the problem you have mentioned and hence, I've posted my answer with few assumptions. Please take a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is based on the following 2 assumptions:

1. `Chiffre_d_affaire__c` field value in the Account object should be based on the following conditions:

   - If the order is deleted, then `Chiffre_d_affaire__c new value = (Chiffre_d_affaire__c current value -  Order amount)`.
   - If the order is added/ updated with *status = 'Activated'*, then `Chiffre_d_affaire__c new value = (Chiffre_d_affaire__c current value +  Order amount)`.
2. Order status can change to a different value after it was set as *Activated* (based on the business logic).

In your case, looks like the following would have happened:

- Order1 created with *Activated* Status with amount as 100000.
- Account 1 Chiffre_d_affaire__c value updated to 100000 by the apex trigger.
- Order1 got processed and status changed from *Activated* to another value.
- Order2 created with Activated Status with order amount as 85000.
- SOQL in the apex trigger will now fetch only Order2 and its amount i.e., 85000 because only Order2 is *Activated* status. Apex Trigger updates the Account 1 Chiffre_d_affaire__c to the same value.

If the above mentioned assumptions and sequence are correct, then the flaw lies in the apex code logic. Also, I see another bug in your code related to the aggregate SOQL query. The following query will always get the total order amount of all orders in activated status for a given account. But, the order status could change anytime and you trigger should consider only the order records that invoked it.

```
AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT AccountId, SUM(TotalAmount)amt FROM Order WHERE AccountId In : accountIds  AND Status = 'Activated' GROUP BY AccountId];
```

You should be incrementing or decrementing the existing Chiffre_d_affaire__c value and not assign the order amount sum. As others have pointed out, you could use the addition assignment operator with the current code logic, but I doubt that alone would help you get rid of all the bugs. Reason being there could be orders in *Activated* status which have been already processed and as new orders get created with *Activated* status, your code would be considering all of them (which is incorrect). This would lead to inflated Chiffre_d_affaire__c value at the account level. You probably should have the trigger as follows considering both order deletion as well as already processed orders.

```
trigger UpdateAccountCA on Order (after update, before delete) {

    Map<Id, Integer> incrementAccountIds = new Map<Id, Integer>();
    Map<Id, Integer> decrementAccountIds = new Map<Id, Integer>();
   
    if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
        //Iterate through each Order
        for(Order o : Trigger.new) {
            if(o.Status == 'Activated' && o.Status != Trigger.oldMap.get(o.AccountId).Status)){
                if(!incrementAccountIds.containsKey(o.AccountId)){
                    incrementAccountIds.put(o.AccountId, o.OrderAmount); // Please update the correct OrderAmount field here
                }
                else{
                    Integer ordAmount = incrementAccountIds.get(o.AccountId) + o.OrderAmount; // Please update the correct OrderAmount field here
                    incrementAccountIds.put(o.AccountId, ordAmount); 
                }   
            }         
        }
    }  
    else if(Trigger.isDelete) {
        for(Order o : Trigger.old) {
            if(!decrementAccountIds.containsKey(o.AccountId)){
                decrementAccountIds.put(o.AccountId, o.OrderAmount); // Please update the correct OrderAmount field here
            }
            else{
                Integer ordAmount = decrementAccountIds.get(o.AccountId) + o.OrderAmount; // Please update the correct OrderAmount field here
                decrementAccountIds.put(o.AccountId, ordAmount); 
            }   
        }
    }
       
    Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, Chiffre_d_affaire__c WHERE Id IN :incrementAccountIds.getKeys() OR Id IN :decrementAccountIds.getKeys()]);
    List<Account> toBeUpdateAccount = new List<Account>();
    
    for(Id accId : accountMap.keySet()){
        
        Integer ordAmount = accountMap.get(accId).Chiffre_d_affaire__c;
        
        if(incrementAccountIds.containsKey(accId){
            ordAmount += incrementAccountIds.get(acc.Id);
        }
        
        if(decrementAccountIds.containsKey(acc.Id){
            ordAmount -= incrementAccountIds.get(acc.Id);
        }
        
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Id = accId;
        acc.Chiffre_d_affaire__c = ordAmount;
        toBeUpdateAccount.add(acc);
    }
    
    update toBeUpdateAccount;
}
```

Note that the above code may have few minor issues, which you might need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.
I have changed the Aggregate query and the set of Chiffre_d_affaire__c field

```
    trigger UpdateAccountCA on Order (after update, before delete) {
    
    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    
    if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
        //Iterate through each Order
        for(Order o : Trigger.new) {
            accountIds.add(o.AccountId);
        }
    }  
    else if(Trigger.isDelete) {
        for(Order o : Trigger.old) {
            accountIds.add(o.AccountId);
        }
    }

    Map<ID, Account> mapAccount = new Map<ID, Account>([SELECT Id, Chiffre_d_affaire__c FROM Account where Id in : accountIds]);
       
    AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT AccountId, SUM(TotalAmount)amt FROM Order WHERE AccountId In : accountIds  AND Status = 'Activated' GROUP BY AccountId];
    
    
    List<Account> toBeUpdateAccount = new List<Account>();
        for(AggregateResult Results: groupedResults) {
            Account acc = new Account();
            acc.Id = (id) Results.get('AccountId');
            acc.Chiffre_d_affaire__c = 
          mapAccount.get(acc.Id).Chiffre_d_affaire__c +  (Decimal)Results.get('amt');
            toBeUpdateAccount.add(acc);
        }
        update toBeUpdateAccount;
    }
```

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for you reply. I have tried to code but I have an error on the query; 

UpdateAccountCA: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.UnexpectedException: field 'Chiffre_d_affaire__c' can not be grouped in a query call Trigger.UpdateAccountCA: line 17, column 1

Comment: I do not have enough information about your field. But the way that you are setting the value is wrong. What you should do is get the value on Chiffre_d_affaire__c and sum with the Order value

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [addition assignment operator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm).

> x += y
>
> Addition assignment operator (Right associative). Adds the value of y to the original value of x and then reassigns the new value to x. x and y cannot be null.

So your code line would be

```
acc.Chiffre_d_affaire__c += (Decimal)Results.get('amt');
```